# Javascript loose augumentation in modular pattern

Tags: javascript

As i am trying to achieve something like this:

```
var SomeModule = (function(parent) {
    var self = parent.Module1 = parent.Module1 || {};
    self.public_property1 = [];
    self.publicMethod1 = function() {
        // something here in the Module2
    }

    return parent;

}(APP || {}));

var SomeOtherModule = (function(parent) {
    var self = parent.Module2 = parent.Module2 || {};
    self.public_property2 = [];
    self.publicMethod2 = function() {
        // something here
    }

    return parent;

}(APP || {}))
```

i get `'Uncaught ReferenceError: APP is not defined'`
But that's the whole point of `APP || {}`, is it not? As i understand, the `parent` argument must contain either the APP object (if it exists), either an empty object.

What i want is APP object to contain Module1, Module2 and any other modules is add.

Am i doing something wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is two-fold.

1) You need to declare your `APP` variable somewhere before you can even reference it (even if you leave the variable as `undefined`). Either that, or you can use the `typeof` operator which does not throw an Error when the variable has not been declared.

2) As you're creating an object on-the-fly (`{}`) in the first instantiation of your `SomeModule`, you're not actually saving a reference of it back to the APP variable, which you seem to want to re-use for the purpose of the second instantiation of `SomeOtherModule`.

Here is a fixed version:

```js
var APP = (function(parent) {
    var self = parent.Module1 = parent.Module1 || {};
    self.public_property1 = [];
    self.publicMethod1 = function() {
        // something here in the Module2
    }

    return parent;

})(APP || {});

APP = (function(parent) {
    var self = parent.Module2 = parent.Module2 || {};
    self.public_property2 = [];
    self.publicMethod2 = function() {
        // something here
    }

    return parent;

})(APP || {});

console.log(APP);
```

As you can see through the console output, the `APP` variable now contains `Module1` and `Module2` values.

I'm not entirely sure what pattern it is that you're trying to represent here (classical inheritance?), but this fix should hopefully keep you moving forward.

Comment: Thanks! this works as expected! I'm just trying different approaches to JS module pattern i guess. I don't fully understand yet, but i'm trying to write better code each day.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a reference to a variable that is undeclared. The whole point of `APP || {}` is to get the empty-object value given that APP is declared and falsy (it can be 0, undefined, false, NaN ...). If it potentially is undeclared, you should use the `typeof` operator to check for it:

```
(function () { ... })(typeof APP !== 'undefined' ? APP : {})
```

Comment: or just declare it before using it: `var APP;`

Comment: @shennan no, that would shadow any previous APP variable and guarantee that it would always be falsy. This situation arose presumably because there is some script-modifying mechanism (maybe server side script) that injects the declaration.

Comment: i still get `Uncaught ReferenceError: APP is not defined` if i console.log(APP). APP should have contain Module1 and Module2

Comment: Again, that is because APP was not declared.

Comment: @sahbeewah I mean declare the `APP` variable at the beginning of the script with any other bootloading logic. Don't presume to know the structure of his application.